# Vue.js beginner: fix changing computed list

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having tasks list divided into completed and in completed

Completed:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="task in tasks" v-if="task.completed">{{task.taskName}}</li>
</ul>
```

In-completed:

```
 <ul>
    <li v-for="(task, index) in incompleteTasks">{{task.taskName}} - {{index}} 
    <button @click="doalert(index)" type="button">make complete</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Script:

```
new Vue({
    el: "#root",
    data: {
        tasks: [
            {taskName: 'planning', completed: true},
            {taskName: 'designing', completed: false},
            {taskName: 'programming', completed: false},
            {taskName: 'testing', completed: false}
        ]
    },
    computed: {
        incompleteTasks(){
            return this.tasks.filter(task => ! task.completed);
        }
    },
    methods: {
        doalert(index){
            var incompleted_tasks = this.tasks.filter(task => ! task.completed);
            incompleted_tasks[index].completed = true;
        }
    }
});
```

First result:

[image]

After clicking the programming button:

[image]

Once I click the button of programming which has index 1 it gets moved to the completed list but clicking any other button doesn't do anything how to fix this? And how to get this item's index in the tasks list itself not in the in-completed tasks only?

Comment: Your code is actually working, I can't reproduce your issue: https://jsfiddle.net/p5hfyw9g/

Comment: There was other code in the page which has method not defined my bad thanks a lot

Comment: That's why its best to create and post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You would have caught this issue yourself and it will make things easier for those trying to help you and increase your chances of quickly getting a solution to your problem. :)